# ASP.NET Core & Swagger : generate multiple outputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I'm using ASP.NET Core with `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen` in version v6.1.5.

I want routes like `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpGet("user")]` in a public `swagger.json` for public endpoints and other routes that contain `internal` inside the route like this `[HttpGet("internal/user/{userGuid}")]` to be in an internal instance of `swagger.json` endpoints.

I configure Swagger in startup in `ConfigureServices` like this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(gen =>
{
    gen.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Server API",
        Version = "1.0",
        Description = "This API features all public available endpoints showing different API features."
    });
    gen.SwaggerDoc("v1-internal", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Viewer Server API (internal)",
        Version = "v1-internal",
        Description = "This API features all public available endpoints showing different API features."
    });
});
```

and in `Configure`

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Viewer Server API v1");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1-internal/swagger.json", "Viewer Server API v1 (internal)");
});
```

How can I get it to create a public and an internal `swagger.json`?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49613813/1752270) what you want?

Comment: @AndrewSilver I'm don't get where the sorting happens, see updated question.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution and will post an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Filtering different `version` or in my case "visibility-layer" can be done like the follwing.
Configure Swagger in startup in `ConfigureServices` like this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(gen =>
{
    gen.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Server API",
        Version = "1.0",
        Description = "This API features all public available endpoints showing different API features."
    });
    gen.SwaggerDoc("v1-internal", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Viewer Server API (internal)",
        Version = "v1-internal",
        Description = "This API features all public available endpoints showing different API features."
    });

    gen.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
    {
        if (docName.Contains("internal"))
        {
            return apiDesc.RelativePath.Contains("internal/");
        }
        else
        {
            return !apiDesc.RelativePath.Contains("internal/");
        }
    });
});
```

and in `Configure`

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Viewer Server API v1");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1-internal/swagger.json", "Viewer Server API v1 (internal)");
});
```

And now you can choose different configurations like in the image below:
[image]